# Spring No Class Found exception when dependency exists

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, dependencies

I am getting the following error which I've researched to be caused by a lack of dependencies or at least thats what the answers were to similar questions. I believe I have all necessary dependencies for the spring framework but it keeps throwing the error. I have run clean on both the server and the project but to no avail. Any input would be great as I'm extremely new to spring and java enterprise apps.

```
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable  
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
org/springframework/context/support/FileSystemXmlApplicationContext
at mycalendar.servlets.EventServlet.init(EventServlet.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1238)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1151)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:828)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Mar 31, 2016 6:13:41 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet eventServlet java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/support/FileSystemXmlApplicationContext
at mycalendar.servlets.EventServlet.init(EventServlet.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1238)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1151)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:828)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

However in my pom file using maven in I do declare the context for the spring framework as seen below:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>MyCalendar</groupId>
  <artifactId>MyCalendar</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0.7</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>


  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

The error is coming from inside my servlet:

@Override
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException
{
    super.init(config);

```
ApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml"); <------here

Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();

Event eventOne = new Event(1, "event 1", "john smith", "12:00am","Fullerton, CA",cal);
Event eventTwo = new Event(2, "event 1", "jane smith", "1:00pm","Placentia,CA",cal);
Event eventThree = new Event(3, "event 3", "jules smith", "2:00pm","Brea, CA",cal);

//Add Dummy Data
eventsDatabase.add(eventOne);
eventsDatabase.add(eventTwo);
eventsDatabase.add(eventThree);

}
```

Project Structure:

[image]

Comment: check you correctly imported or not?

Comment: @subburoyal what do you mean by that?

Answer (score 1):

Seeing the your code I can see that you define a pom.xml but since that your project isn't a maven project infact you didn't have a project structure like below

```
src
 - main
   - java
     - .....
   - resource
     - ....
   - webapp
      WEB-INF
       - ....
      .....
 - test
    - java
      - .....
    - resource
      - ....
```

for this reason you set the pom for the dependency packaging and so on but you cant'use maven probably you are using the eclipse ide for build the war, and eclipse probably didn't pakage correctly the your dependency under lib folder under WEB-INF. You have manually set eclipse for pakage correctly the depndency.

The my advice was refactor the your code for benefit of maven with a structure that I described above, make eclipse aware tha tyou have a maven project setting the maven nature, and don't use in general  FileSystemXmlApplicationContext for a web aplication. you sould use a structure like this:

configure the your Spring web context: getRootConfigClasses for the @Configuration class of the your root Spring context, and getServletConfigClasses for the your @Configuration class for the your web context

```
public class PhoneBookServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] {PhonBookApplicationContext.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] {PhoneBookMvcContext.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] {"/"};
    }
}
```

configure the your spring web context like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"it.valeriovaudi.web.controller","it.valeriovaudi.web.rest"})
@EnableWebMvc
public class PhoneBookMvcContext extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

//    Thymeleaf Config
/*
*  <bean id="templateResolver"
         class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver"
         p:prefix="/WEB-INF/templates/"
         p:templateMode="HTML5"
         p:suffix=".html"/>
     <bean id="templateEngine"
         class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine"
         p:templateResolver-ref="templateResolver">
         <property name="additionalDialects">
         <set>
         <bean class="org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity3.dialect.SpringSecurityDialect"/>
         </set>
         </property>
     </bean>
     <bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver"
            p:templateEngine-ref="templateEngine"/>
    */
    @Bean
    public ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver(){
        ServletContextTemplateResolver servletContextTemplateResolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
        servletContextTemplateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/");
        servletContextTemplateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        servletContextTemplateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");

        return servletContextTemplateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine(){
        SpringTemplateEngine springTemplateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        springTemplateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        springTemplateEngine.setAdditionalDialects(Collections.singleton(new SpringSecurityDialect()));
        return springTemplateEngine;
    }

    @Bean
    public ThymeleafViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver(){
        ThymeleafViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        thymeleafViewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());

        return thymeleafViewResolver;
    }

    /*
    Message .properties sources
    <bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource"
    p:basenames="WEB-INF/messages/messages"/>
    */

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource(){
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource reloadableResourceBundleMessageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        reloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.setBasenames("WEB-INF/messages/messages");

        return reloadableResourceBundleMessageSource;
    }
   /*
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources*//**" location="web-resources/, classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/favicon.ico" location="web-resources/img/favicon.jpg" />
     */

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        super.addResourceHandlers(registry);

        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("web-resources/").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/favicon.ico").addResourceLocations("web-resources/img/favicon.jpg");
    }

}
```

for this sample I take ispiration from a my open source project PhoneBook but the key point is that you have configure the your context like above independently form the configured bean, take example for the kind of class that you have configure and the project structure that you need have for use maven.

I hope tha ttis can help you